# What would be the best strategy to take a RTP stream and send it to an RTMP server?

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp, rtp

I'm receiving a RTP/UDP from a hardware encoder, I have tried ffmpeg, so it takes this input and outputs the stream as FLV (it's being sent to NGINX, nginx-rtmp-module). However I'm not able to play the stream smoothly once it's received by nginx, some frames are broken or lost, etc.

I think that my CPU is too slow for this format change (FLV) and/or ffmpeg is missing a lot of RTP packets. Any ideas?